# Megamenu implementation on Shopify Store. CSS gets messed up

Tags: javascript, css, shopify

I have tried in this regard as follows. All can contribute

1. Found a fantastic mega menu implemnt at `https://www.cssscript.com/demo/responsive-mega-menu/`   This is open avaiable.
2. Copied relevant html+css and javascript.
3. Put html + CSS in a `.liquid` file (`megamenu.liquid`) togather and javascript in separate .js file (say,`megamenu-liquid-support.js`) . Put `<script src="{{ 'megamenu-liquid-support.js' | asset_url }}"> </script>` at the end of html of megamenu.liquid
4. Opened header.liquid file of Shopify Dawn theme.
5. Commented lines 159 to 346 which are responsible for display of menu.
6. On line no. 347, put the tag `{% render 'megamenu.liquid' %}` to render it on screen. Uptill here, we are talking about lines in header.liquid
7. Now, you need to put a small code (in `megamenu.liquid`)as follows starting from line no.54 to 71 and comment out line no. 72 to 133. Basically, commenting it will disable hard coded CSS and below code will implement link list menu from shopify. Also put `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/4.6.3/css/ionicons.min.css">` at beginning of megamenu.liquid. The code to be put is as mentioned below:
8. Vola ! You have megamenu functional on yourshopify site. Icing on the cake - it will be functional on mobile as well !!!
9. Now the problem part, after you do above you will have functinal menu because now CSS gets messed up and font size etc becomes weired on every page of shopify store. **Any solution to this.** I came up to this and hope someone will definately get help from this and some veteran can help us out also.

```html
 <li class="menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#">Category <i class="ion ion-ios-arrow-down"></i></a>
              <div class="menu-subs menu-mega menu-column-4">
                 {%- for link in section.settings.menu.links -%}
                    <div class="list-item">
                       <h4 class="title">{{ link.title | escape }}</h4>
                        <ul >
                           {%- for childlink in link.links -%}
                              <li> <a id="mega_headerMenu-{{ link.handle }}-{{ childlink.handle }}" href="{{ childlink.url }}" >{{ childlink.title | escape }} </a> </li>
                           {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                {% endfor %}

                <div class="list-item">
                  <img src="<<Put image link here"  class="responsive"  width="300" height="173" alt="Shop Product">
                </div>
                 </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: I commented html{} tag in the ```megamenu.liquid``` file and CSS is taken care. Now balance thing is to ensure that other content appears below this newly created megamenu and not behind. Let us see. But it is functional now...

Comment: Adjusting the margin of .header{} has done the trick

Answer (score 0):

Update:1
I commented html{} tag in the megamenu.liquid file and CSS is taken care. Now balance thing is to ensure that other content appears below this newly created megamenu and not behind. Let us see. But it is functional now... –

Update: 2
Adjusting the margin of .header{} has done the trick. Mega menu is working now.